# MUI-Autocomplete does not update value on select

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm using React and Material-UI framework for a project and want to implement the MUI-Autocomplete Component. I do get the options displaying as they're meant to be but upon selecting one of these options the Input field goes blank and even the state remains unchanged.
I also tried the demo on the website and couldn't get it to work. 
Here's the code. Take a look at output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FX5f.png). 
[Link to video showing output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn339.jpg)

```
 <Autocomplete
 id="combo-box-demo"
 options={this.props.products}
 getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
 style={{ width: 300 }}
 renderInput={params => (
 <TextField
    {...params}
    label="Combo box"
    variant="outlined"
    fullWidth
 />
)}/>
```

I could not replicate the problem on CodeSandbox but here's the link to it.
[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-sun-d2248?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: You do not have an `onChange` therefore nothing can happen.

Comment: I did add an `onChange` event and until I select one of the options it does edit the state but as soon as I select the option it does not work.  [Here's a video of  what happens.](https://imgur.com/a/zbzs16V)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem. The code shown in your question text is not sufficient for understanding your problem.

Comment: I've edited my post with a link to CodeSandbox. Could not get the issue to replicate but it still is the same on my computer.

Answer (score -3):

```
onSelectCapture={this.handleChange}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Code-only answers are discouraged here.  Can you please add more context and/or explanation as to how this helps the original question?

Comment: there is no such prop of the Autocomplete component in Material-UI
https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/